# Bulma: Unable to use both is-static and is-primary modifies on a button

Tags: css, bulma

I want to create a button using Bulma that is non-interactive and a "primary" button.  Here is my attempt:

```
<span class="button is-primary is-static">Hello World</span>
```

When I do this, I get a standard looking non-interactive button.  It's gray in color and not clickable (this is NOT a disabled button).  The `is-primary` modifier seems to have no effect on the button and I am unsure why.  If I were to instead remove the `is-static` modifier, I get a normal looking "primary" button.

I found a hack-ish solution (by doing the following) but would prefer to use the modifiers provided by Bulma instead.

```css
.button.non-interactive {
    background-color: $my-custom-primary-color !important;
    color: $white !important;
    border: hsl(0, 0%, 86%);
}
```

```
<span class="button non-interactive is-static">Hello World</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the color properties of `is-static` overrides `is-primary`.
I find this behavior normal because a static button with a color doesn't really looks like a static button...
To be sure, I've created the following buttons : on the left it's a button with `is-primary`, and on the right a button with `is-static` and `non-reactive` reproduced with your code adapted with my primary color.

[image]

And I didn't see any difference on the design, I just noticed that the pointer events were disabled and the right one, so I checked in the console to verify the changes made by `is-static` on the right button :

[image]

And indeed, `is-static` is just disabling `pointer-events` and `box-shadow` (useless for `box-shadow` in this case).

So if you want a non-interactive button with a color, I would advice you to use this class :

```
.button.non-interactive {
    pointer-events: none;  /* Imitate the behavior of is-static class */
    box-shadow: none;  /* Optional, it might be useful in cases where the button is in a container with a box-shadow */
}
```

And use it in your button with `is-primary` or any other color class :

```
<span class="button non-interactive is-primary">Hello World</span>
```